# creating two dimensional hashset functionality

Tags: java

I am trying to make two dimensional hashset functionality. I have a loop that iterates through pairs of integers:

```
        ResultSet getAssociations;
        Statement getAssociationsSelect = sqlConn
                .createStatement();
        getAssociations = getAssociationsSelect
                .executeQuery("SELECT ProductId, ThemeId FROM ProductTheme");
        while(getAssociations.next()) {
            int productId1 = getAssociations.getInt(1);
            int themeId1 = getAssociations.getInt(2);
        }
```

When the current pair of integers does not match a previous pair of integers I want to store them. I figured a hashset would be the best approach because I can insert the pairs and it wont take repeats. How do I do this?

Comment: do you know how large the id's can be?

Comment: I dont anticipate they will ever go over 10000

Comment: wouldn't a hashmap be a better approach?

Comment: What if you concatenated the two numbers into a string, like "321-32"

Comment: Any reason not to `SELECT DISTINCT ProductId, ThemeId`?

Comment: Question: Is ProductId going to be unique, or can ProductId map to more than one ThemeId?

Comment: My first idea would be a little helper class holding the two integers. Override the hashCode method, so you are sure, that two instance are equal if and only if the productIds are equal and the themeIds are equal. HashSet should do the rest.

Comment: I believe the key cant be repeated in a hashmap? I want both 1, 2 and 1, 3 to be able to be added. Just not two pairs of 1,2 for example.

Comment: ProductId maps to more than one themeId

Comment: David, are the keys ever meant to be used independently?  In other words, will you ever want to get a list of all values (or all key pairs) mapped to a particular ProductId, regardless of their ThemeId or vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a really simple solution concatenate both keys and store the resulting string, e.g.

```
String newKey = String.format( "%d-%d.", productId1 , themeId1 );
```

It will allways generate a unique key for each combination.

Answer (score 4):

I think you might be over-thinking the problem a bit.  I would suggest the following:

```
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer, Set<Integer>>();
if(!map.containsKey(productId))
    map.put(productId, new HashSet<Integer>());
map.get(productId).add(themeId);
```

This way you have a `Set` of all the `themeIds` that map to a given `productId`, guaranteeing uniqueness while creating an object with an easily iterable format.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new object which can act as a composite key based on productId1 and themeId1. Make sure and implement the equals and hashCode methods and store these objects in the Set.

```
public class AssociationReference() {
    private int productId;
    private int themeId;

    //constructor/getters/setters

    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + productId;
        result = prime * result + themeId;

        return result;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

    }

}
```

Now you can use HashSet and only unique values will be stored. You can also use this Object as the Key on a HashMap if you need to store more.

I would avoid creating a key by conjoining values unless you are sure that the ranges will never change, and that you ca careful to pad your numbers so there can be no collision (i.e 9 and 11 should be 00090011 rather than 911 so as to be distinguishable from 91 and 1).

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `HashMap<Long, Association>`

As Keys i would use `ProductId * 1000000 + ThemeId` so they look like this:

```
32000064 for ProductId = 32 and ThemeId = 64
```

be sure to implement `equals` and `hashcode`in your `Association` class

Comment: Even simpler is to use a HashSet<Long>, and combine the two integers into the high/low ends of the long.  This way you don't need to worry about overflow or an ID longer than you initially expected.